# How do we extract the bigpicturestyle image from android notifications?

Tags: android

I have a notification listener service that reads notifications from other apps (with the user's permission) and extracts all the data. Able to access everything except the image shown in the expanded view of the notification.
I am also reading the EXTRA_PICTURE intent value

```
if (extras.containsKey(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE)) {
        // this bitmap contain the picture attachment
        try {
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);
            ByteArrayOutputStream picStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, picStream);
            byte[] picBmpData = picStream.toByteArray();
            notificationPicture = Base64.encodeToString(picBmpData, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This works sometimes but for all notifications with image in their expanded view. Am I missing anything?

UPDATE: more clarification on what happens in the negative cases:
In negative cases when there is an image in the notification, the extras dont seem to have the EXTRA_PICTURE key set. However I do see

> android.template

key set to

> android.app.Notification$BigPictureStyle

Comment: You haven't explained what does happen. Maybe the issue is with the convert. Try setting an imageView with the bitmap  `imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp)`