# Extracting the Image from Notification through Notification listener Service

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, notification-listener

I have the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068995/how-do-we-extract-the-bigpicturestyle-image-from-android-notifications) but it seems like the android is unable to extract one through extras key values. The extras don't seem to have the ***EXTRA_PICTURE***   key set. I am in dire need of a solution to this.